proofing algebraic limit theorem
Let $(a_n)$ and $(x_n)$ be sequences of real number such that $|x_n - x| \le C|a_n|$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$, for some $C > 0$ and $x \in \mathbb{R}$. if $\lim_{n\to\infty}(a_n) = 0$, proof that $\lim_{n\to\infty}(x_n) = x$.

Presumably your question should start with "Let $(a_n)$ and $(x_n)$..." rather than $b_n$.

Given $\frac{\epsilon}{C} > 0$, because $\lim_{n\to\infty}(a_n) = 0$, then there are exists $K \in \mathbb{N}$ so that for all $n > K$ satisfy $|a_n - 0| = |a_n| < \frac{\epsilon}{C}$
therefore
$|x_n - x| \le C|a_n| < C\frac{\epsilon}{C} = \epsilon$  thus $\lim_{n\to\infty}(x_n) = x$.
